# In Lightswitch, how can one include a subquery in a Grid?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Im building an app in Lightswitch becasue I thought it was a good fit for a Rapid CRUD situation i need to address. 
The app has Groups, Each Group can have many Members, and Each Member can have many Issues.
I have defined the 3 tables in lightswitch and can effectively CRUD everything in 1 hour in any device (Im using HTML client) - impressive.
However I would like to add a couple of niceties, and the one im struggling with is how to add a subquery for a column in a lightswitch grid.
So in the Members "Browse" Grid, I basically wanted to add a column: "Date Of Last Issue". In SQL I would simply have (simplified):

SELECT m.*,
DateOfLastIssue = (SELECT Top 1 [Date] FROM Issue i WHERE i.MemberID = m.Id)
FROM Members

Is there anyway to get that DateOfLastIssue subquery into the lightswitch browse grid?
Thank you very much in advance for your time if you have read this far.
Any ideas welcome.

***Additional Info***
I tried adding a compute column that returns the result, but the Member grid doesn't allow me to add the computed column to it..

Answer (score 1):

Remember, Lightswitch lets you create objects based on views. Create the view with the date of last issue and add it to the datasource. And YES! You will even be able to edit the view (if need be).

Answer (score 0):

Add a computed field.  For the method that populates the field, execute a Linq-to-Entities query that computes the value for the current row.  Shouldn't be hard.

Alternatively, create a new DataSource pointing to a view on the required table.  The view can then be linked to the primary table as required for CRUD updates using the table's PK.  Query the VIEW for read operations, and the TABLE for create/update/delete operations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Ozziemedes, Ill give it a try. The last time I tried, it wouldn't allow me to add a computed column to the list/grid view. The view is a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. :)  Another trick is to use a T-SQL Scalar function to get the required aggregate value - Max(Date) in this case - based on the PK of the row.  That will let you embed the scalar function as a row in the table.  Or you could include the scalar function in the table itself as a computed column. :)

Comment: I know this is an old post but would you mind adding some more detail to this answer? I'm trying to do something similar but don't have the first idea about how to do what you're suggesting - although it looks like it might fix my problem!